# python psd tools to create mask

Tags: python, graphics, mask, photoshop

I want to make an psd file from two different bitmap images one source, and another as mask (in black and white) and have layers as shown:

[image: What I want to have]

I tried to make it with psd_tools

so far I made a psd from the source but I did not find a method from the library to apply a mask from a pils' image.

I have so far :

```
from PIL import Image

from psd_tools import PSDImage
from psd_tools.api.mask import Mask



source = Image.open('source.png')

mask_img = Image.open('mask.png')


psd = PSDImage.frompil(source)

layers = psd.compose()

# I need to make a mask here

psd.save('img.psd')
```

I know that psd file are not open format, if anyone know another solution involving other format that can contain editable mask (tiff can handle it too for instance), it would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Nope, I did not resolve the issue